# How to fetch elements from a page where its reference/link is provided in .js page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm Using AJAX to dynamically fetch data from my php page (which contains html) and display it on another html page. Its fetching the whole data. But I want only the info under `<table>` and `<p id="recent">`.
 How to do that? Here is the [link to the page](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/blog-post.html#)

HTML Page where the call is made and result should be displayed

```
    <h3><a href="#" id="get">John</a></h3> 
    <div> 
        <p class="post">Result to be displayed</p> 
    </div>
```

AJAX code

```
   $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    //  load() functions

    var loadUrl = "../load.php";
        $("#get").click(function(){
        $(".post")
            .html(ajax_load)
            .load(loadUrl, "language=php&version=5");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
$('#get').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    'url' : 'yoururl.php',
    'type' : 'GET',
    'success' : function(data) {
      $('p.post').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Answer (score 1):

This will load just the `<table>` and `<p id="recent-post">` from the other page.

```
$("#get").click(function() {
    var loadUrl = "../load.php?language=php&version=5";
    $(".post").load(loadUrl + ' table, #recent-post');
});
```

Comment: Edit: In this case, no need to add wrapper <div> (though it would probably be better in the long run). The .load() function will just pull out the "table" and "p#recent-post"

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to:

```
.load(loadUrl+" #recent", "language=php&version=5");
```

to get the `<div id="recent">` or

```
.load(loadUrl+" table", "language=php&version=5");
```

for `<table>`.

jQuery's load function has a feature where you can define a selector to load data from as well as the page. http://api.jquery.com/load/